# Calling a Jasper Server report from jsp

Tags: web-services, jsp, jasperserver

I'm a newbie to this area and need help.

I'm working with Jasper reports server. My goal is to call a report published in JasperServer from a jsp. Is it possible?

Until now I was able to show a report on a html page using http api, but the problem there is that user credential are in cleartext and not hidden.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all yours suggestion i came up with this solution:

```
PutMethod put = new PutMethod(request3);
put.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(descriptor, "text/xml", "UTF-8"));
int statusCode3 = client.executeMethod(put);
//System.out.println(put.getResponseBodyAsString());
String report = put.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Simply i found a way to set up the body of my PUT HTTP request and everything works fine!
I posted the solution maybe can help someone!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Rest API](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api) of JasperServer and use some rest clients like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to get the response of your report as input stream and render that in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are helpful to you.

[Calling a .jasper file from a JSP](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/308549/calling-a-.jasper-file-from-a-jsp#)

[Streaming a PDF Jasper Report Using JSP](http://bekwam.blogspot.com/2011/06/streaming-pdf-jasper-report-using-jsp.html)